# How to automate health check up in remote system?

Tags: outlook-2007, health-monitoring

I need to check the disk space in a number of remote systems (Windows 2000) and have to sent a mail if the space is below a particular level. How can this be automated? What script can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be a system monitoring tool, such as [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/).

Basically, what this will do is continually interrogate your systems, and alert you to anything you set it to (disk-space, CPU usage, page-faults, etc.). As a bonus you get a lovely web-based interface which lets you see your system status at a glance.

Note that you will need to enable remote WMI querying on each target system, or install an "agent" on each system.

Comment: @ RB I accept with you RB. But i dont have rights to install software on the remote systems. It would be fine if this can be done using any scripts....

Comment: @trilawney Nagios is not installed on the remote system. The only thing that needs to be done on the remote system is to enable remote WMI querying. If you can't enable **this**, then the obvious route for writing a script is closed to you!